# Trying so save user data to dbcontext after first signup with Auth0 in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, auth0

What I am trying to achieve: 
1. Getting all the claims after OnTicketReceived event from Auth0. 
2. Checking if the user is signing up for first time (bool value in 1 of the claims).
3. Saving new user object into localdb (if it's the first time logging in).
Currently I am stuck on third step.
In order to use OnTicketReceived I need a static method on the right side but then I cannot use DbContext in my controller class because it is not a static variable.

Startup.cs

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            ...
            .AddOpenIdConnect("Auth0", options =>
            {
                options.Scope.Add("openid");
                ...
                options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
                {
                    OnTicketReceived = UsersController.CreateOnSignUp,
                ...
                };
            });
```

UsersController.cs

```
        public static async Task<Task> CreateOnSignUp(TicketReceivedContext ticketReceivedContext)
        {
            List<Claim> claims = ticketReceivedContext.Principal.Claims.ToList();
            var claim = claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type.EndsWith("isNewUser"));
            bool isNewUser = bool.Parse(claim.Value);

            if (isNewUser)
            {
                string userOId = claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
                User user = new User() { ExternalId = userOId };
                //insert new value into DB
                //_context.Add(user);
                //await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
```

Commented code lines are currently not working.
Could anyone recommend a better way of saving user data to DB after authentication or a workaround to my current solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the controllers are instantiated per call (or for each HTTP request). You shouldn't maintain any state by introducing static properties, fields or methods inside the controllers.

In your case, I would create a service class `ServiceSignUp` that consists of the `CreateOnSignUp` method.

```
 public interface IServiceSignUp
 {
    async Task CreateOnSignUp(TicketReceivedContext ticketReceivedContext);
 }

 public class ServiceSignUp : IServiceSignUp
 {
    public async Task CreateOnSignUp(TicketReceivedContext ticketReceivedContext)
    {
       ....
    } 
 }
```

Then register them with the build-in IoC container like `services.AddSingleton<IServiceSignUp, ServiceSignUp>();`

In the `ConfigureServices()` method inside the `StartUp` class:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<IServiceSignUp, ServiceSignUp>();

    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
                ...

            .AddOpenIdConnect("Auth0", options =>
            {
                options.Scope.Add("openid");
                ...
                options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
                {
                    OnTicketReceived += ServiceSignUp.CreateOnSignUp,
                    ...
                };
            });
}
```

Comment: Do you have a suggestion how to use database context in your example in order to save new users?

Comment: @Smacl3r It depends on the architecture of your application.  Do you have a repository layer that handles all the DB operations?  Just based on your original posting, You would inject the DbContext in the constructor of the `ServiceSignUp` class.  Then use it like you do in your example.  A well designed app will use factories, unit of work patterns, among others.

Comment: seems like injecting into constructor was enough for us but we also needed to change registration of ServiceSignUp from Singleton to Scope. Thank you.
There is 1 warning from your solution when trying to BuildServiceProvider: Calling 'BuildServiceProvider' from application code results in an additional copy of singleton services being created. Consider alternatives such as dependency injecting services as parameters to 'Configure'.
Seems like at the end there will be two service providers and that might not be good in some cases. Can that be avoided?

Comment: Where do you see the warning?

Comment: `public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            ...
            services.AddDbContext<dbcontext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));         
            services.AddControllersWithViews();        
            services.AddScoped<IServiceSignUp, ServiceSignUp>();          
            var serviceProvider =` **services.BuildServiceProvider();**            
           `var serviceSignUp = serviceProvider.GetService<IServiceSignUp>();         
            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {...});}`

Comment: You can remove the line:  `var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider(); var serviceSignUp = serviceProvider.GetService<IServiceSignUp>();`